# Reference to class persisting in loop

Tags: php, loops, class, memory, php-7.1

I create a bunch of instances of a basic class via a loop.
Each iteration, I add (by reference, not copy) the instance to an array.

**Why is it that after the loop, every reference in the array is to the last instance created?**

Doing an unset seems to fix the issue, however I don't believe this is ideal and could potentially unset the underlying instance from memory.

```
<?php
//foobars remembers something
class FOOBAR{
    public $val;
    public function __construct(&$input){
        $this->val = $input;
    }
};

//after creating foobars, pass them to a list
$list1 = [];
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
    //create an instance of foobar
    $random = rand(1, 10);
    $instance = new FOOBAR($random);
    $list1[] = &$instance;

    // Using unset (below) fixes it?
    //unset($instance);
}

//show what our foobars remembered
var_dump(json_encode($list1));
?>
```

Comment: `$list1[] = $instance;` would work. But not sure **why** it doesn't work with `&`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
$list1[] = &$instance;
```

The item in your array contains a reference to the `$instance` variable. As soon as you change that variable - in the next iteration of the loop in your case - the item in the array references the newly create item.

So after the loop all entries in the array reference the last object you created.

You need:

```
$list1[] = $instance;
```

Comment: I'd have thought $instance was holding a reference to the class created via "new". I did not realize $instance itself is storing the instance. Likely  I expected "new" and classes to work similar to C/C++ ! Cheers.